# Changing how a longpress is executed

Tags: led, button, rgb-led

I have an RGB LED common Anode attached to my Uno and this code detects a long press to turn the LED on and off.  Short presses cycle through colors, then off.

The problem is that a longpress is 2+sec, but it doesn't register until I release the button.  How would I set this up to execute the code at 2sec regardless of whether the button is released?

It's probably not worth my time if it requres too much modification.  I have a working item, it's just not... ideal.

```c
Xhunsigned long keyPrevMillis = 0;
const unsigned long keySampleIntervalMs = 25;

int redPin = 11;
int greenPin = 10;
int bluePin = 9;
int LEDcolor=0; // 0=White, 1=Red, 2=Green, 3-Blue, 4=Yellow, 5=Purple, 6=Pink, 7=Orange, 8=Off 
int LEDstatus =0; //0=Off, 1=On
int changed =0; //has the LEDstatus just changed?
byte longKeyPressCountMax = 80;    // 80 * 25 = 2000 ms
byte longKeyPressCount = 0;

byte prevKeyState = HIGH;         // button is active low
const byte keyPin = 2;            // button is connected to pin 2 and GND

// called when button is kept pressed for less than 2 seconds
void shortKeyPress() 
{
   Serial.println("short");
   if (LEDstatus==1)
   {
      LEDcolor = LEDcolor +1;
      if (LEDcolor==0) {analogWrite(redPin, 0);analogWrite(greenPin, 0);analogWrite(bluePin, 0);Serial.println("White");}
      if (LEDcolor==1) {analogWrite(redPin, 0);analogWrite(greenPin, 255);analogWrite(bluePin, 255);Serial.println("Red");}
      if (LEDcolor==2) {analogWrite(redPin, 255);analogWrite(greenPin, 0);analogWrite(bluePin, 255);Serial.println("Green");}
      if (LEDcolor==3) {analogWrite(redPin, 255);analogWrite(greenPin, 255);analogWrite(bluePin, 0);Serial.println("Blue");}
      if (LEDcolor==4) {analogWrite(redPin, 0);analogWrite(greenPin, 0);analogWrite(bluePin, 255);Serial.println("Yellow");}
      if (LEDcolor==5) {analogWrite(redPin, 175);analogWrite(greenPin, 255);analogWrite(bluePin, 175);Serial.println("Purple");}
      if (LEDcolor==6) {analogWrite(redPin, 0);analogWrite(greenPin, 255);analogWrite(bluePin, 155);Serial.println("Pink");}
      if (LEDcolor==7) {analogWrite(redPin, 5);analogWrite(greenPin, 215);analogWrite(bluePin, 255);Serial.println("Orange");}
      if (LEDcolor==8) {analogWrite(redPin, 255);analogWrite(greenPin, 255);analogWrite(bluePin, 255);Serial.println("Off");LEDstatus=0;}
   }
}

// called when button is kept pressed for more than 2 seconds
void longKeyPress() 
{
   Serial.println("long");
   if (LEDstatus==0 && changed==0)
   {
      analogWrite(redPin, 0);
      analogWrite(greenPin, 0); 
      analogWrite(bluePin, 0);
      LEDcolor=0;
      changed=1;
      LEDstatus=1;Serial.println("On");
   }
   if (LEDstatus==1 && changed==0)
   {
      analogWrite(redPin, 255);
      analogWrite(greenPin, 255); 
      analogWrite(bluePin, 255);
      LEDcolor=0;
      changed=1;
      LEDstatus=0;Serial.println("Off");
   }
   changed=0;
}

// called when key goes from not pressed to pressed
void keyPress() {
   Serial.println("key press");
   longKeyPressCount = 0;
}


// called when key goes from pressed to not pressed
void keyRelease() {
   Serial.println("key release");

   if (longKeyPressCount >= longKeyPressCountMax) {
      longKeyPress();
   }
   else {
      shortKeyPress();
   }
}

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(keyPin, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(keyPin, HIGH);
   pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT); 
   analogWrite(redPin, 255);
   analogWrite(greenPin, 255); 
   analogWrite(bluePin, 255);
}

void loop() {
// key management section
   if (millis() - keyPrevMillis >= keySampleIntervalMs) {
      keyPrevMillis = millis();

      byte currKeyState = digitalRead(keyPin);

      if ((prevKeyState == HIGH) && (currKeyState == LOW)) {
         keyPress();
      }
      else if ((prevKeyState == LOW) && (currKeyState == HIGH)) {
         keyRelease();
      }
      else if (currKeyState == LOW) {
         longKeyPressCount++;
      }

      prevKeyState = currKeyState;
   }
}
```

Comment: The button watcher will have to become aware of time, or be able to be alerted that the short-press time has been exceeded. How much trouble and whether it's worth it is up to your own cost (labor) vs. benefit preference, but it's probably a worthwhile learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten the code entirely. Not that yours was terrible, it was just easier for me to start from scratch. You are left with a very empty `loop()`, which I always prefer.

The code contains three 'colours' and an OFF state. You can add as many other colours as you wish: add an enumeration to `_LED_STATE` and then add a corresponding `case(<NEW_COLOUR>)` statement in `LEDcontrol()`. I haven't included any `analogWrite()` functions - or in fact any declarations for the LED pins at all - because I'm a little too lazy but it should be obvious where to put them within the case statement.

Note that in the final `case()` statement, the LED state is changed from green to off. This means that a short press will turn the LED off after it has cycled through all the other colours, but will stay off until a long press. If you only want long pressed to switch off/on, change line 103 to `eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_RED;`, or whichever the first colour is.

```c
#define btn 3   // button pin

#define SHORT_PRESS 100     // useful for debouncing, can be changed
#define LONG_PRESS  2000    // defines how long a 'long press' is
#define CYCLE       false
#define SHOW        true

//--// You can add new colours in this enum block
enum _LED_STATE
{
    _LED_STATE_OFF,
    _LED_STATE_RED,
    _LED_STATE_BLUE,
    _LED_STATE_GREEN
};

_LED_STATE eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_OFF;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(btn, OUTPUT);
    LEDcontrol(SHOW);
}

void loop()
{

    if (digitalRead(btn))
        btnPressed();
}

void btnPressed()
{
    unsigned long tStart = millis();

    //--// Loop continuously while button is pressed
    while (digitalRead(btn))
    {
        //--// If LONG_PRESS is exceeded...
        if (millis() > tStart + LONG_PRESS)
        {
            //--// If LED is off, turn it on
            if (eLED_STATE == _LED_STATE_OFF)
                eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_RED;        // Choose 'starting' colour
            //--// If LED is on, turn if off
            else
                eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_OFF;
            //--// Update LED to display new eLED_STATE
            LEDcontrol(SHOW);
            //--// Now loop here until button is released
            while (digitalRead(btn));
        }
    }

    //--// If button is released in between the two press times
    if ((millis() > tStart + SHORT_PRESS) && (millis() < tStart + LONG_PRESS))
    {
        //--// Ignore if LED is off         ////// REMOVE ////////////////////
        if (eLED_STATE == _LED_STATE_OFF)   ////////// IF ////////////////////
            return;                         ///////////// NECESSARY //////////

        //--// Change the LED colour
        LEDcontrol(CYCLE);
        //--// Update LED to display new eLED_STATE
        LEDcontrol(SHOW);
    }

    //--// This helps to debounce; experiment with it
    delay(10);
}

void LEDcontrol(bool SHOW_OR_CYCLE)
{
    switch (eLED_STATE)
    {
        case(_LED_STATE_RED) :
        {
            if (SHOW_OR_CYCLE)
            {
                // paint it red
                return;
            }
            eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_GREEN;
            return;
        }
        case(_LED_STATE_GREEN) :
        {
            if (SHOW_OR_CYCLE)
            {
                // paint it green
                return;
            }
            eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_BLUE;
            return;
        }
        case(_LED_STATE_BLUE) :
        {
            if (SHOW_OR_CYCLE)
            {
                // paint it blue
                return;
            }
            //--// What happens after last colour? Next colour or OFF?
            eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_OFF;
            return;
        }
        case(_LED_STATE_OFF) :
        {
            if (SHOW_OR_CYCLE)
            {
                // paint it black
                return;
            }
            eLED_STATE = _LED_STATE_RED;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```